# Prism Library Dialog Service

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, prism

The following sample never worked for me:
https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html

Where the dialogService comming from?

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
}
```

How can I add the dialog service?

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        var w = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        return w;
    }
```

It's have to go within the RegisterTypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where the dialogService comming from?

From the container. When resolving, the container also resolves all dependencies.

> How can I add the dialog service?

You don't have to and normally should shouldn't either. Most of the time, the default implementation provided by the prism framework suffices.

> It's have to go within the RegisterTypes?

If you use Unity, every non-concrete type has to be registered to be able to be resolved. That means, prism's dialog service implementation is registered somewhere. Have a look at the code of your application's base class as a starting point.